# Issue Looping through String Array

Tags: apex

I am trying to loop through an array but having an issue
First I have a text field that I convert into list:

```
List<String> jobIds;

if(newProgram.Job_List__c != null){
   jobIds = newProgram.Job_List__c.split(',');
}
```

Data looks like:
jobIds : ([{"jId":"#############"}, {jId":"###########"}])

Then I try to loop through the List

```
if(jobIds != null && !jobIds.isEmpty()){
   for(String jids : jobIds){
      tempJobId = jids.jId
}
```

This gives an error in the debug but does not state what the error is.
Can I not loop through jobIds?

Cheers,
P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jids.jId` is not valid syntax.
With that code, you're trying to access the "jId" instance variable of "jids"
"jids" is a string, which has no instance variables, hence it is a syntax error

Further, your example `Job_List__c` data appears to be *JSON*. Using `String.split()` on JSON data is not the way to handle it. If you were to `system.debug()` the result of splitting on the comma, you would see
`[{"jId":"#############"}` as the first string out of the split, and `{jId":"###########"}]` as the second.

Instead, you should be using `JSON.deserialize()` here, and create a simple deserialization class to use with it.

As an example, for the JSON `[{"someKey":"value"}]`...

```java
public class KeyValDeserialized {
    // Variable name matches the name of the key in the JSON
    // The type you use matches the type of the value in the JSON
    public String someKey;
}

String myJSON = '[{"someKey":"value"}]';

// There's a few things going on here
// 1: since the JSON is a list (starts and ends with '[' and ']'), we need to 
//   deserialize into a list
// 2: since JSON.deserialize returns an Object, we need to do some typecasting
// 3: the "KeyValDeserialized.class" bit gets you a reference to the type/class
//   that you're deserializing into. This is required for JSON.deserialize(), but
//   you could instead use JSON.deserializeUntyped and skip the need for the
//   KeyValDeserialized class entirely (if you don't mind doing more typecasting)
List<KeyValDeserialized> data = (List<KeyValDeserialized>)JSON.deserialize(myJSON, KeyValDeserialized.class);

for(KeyValDeserialized datum :data){
    // access the value using dot-notation like with any other class
    system.debug(datum.someKey);
}
```